# javascript - convert date to long based on the language specific format

Tags: javascript, datetime, date, prototypejs

I have two date pickers one for startDate and another one is for endDate.

The date pickers is returning me values in following formats, based on the language of the application :

```
language selected by user    datepicker value(start and end)
========================     ===============================
          en                     03/30/2012 | 04/12/2012
          es                     30/03/2012 | 12/04/2012
```

My javascript code is something like :

```
var startDate = new Date ($('startDate'+counter).value);
var endDate = new Date($('endDate'+counter).value);

if(endDate.getTime() > startDate.getTime()){
//if part logic
}
else{
// else part logic
}
```

above code is working fine with en language, but failing with es, because of the different date format in the datepicker.

That means `endDate.getTime()` and `startDate.getTime()` is returning wrong value in case of `es` language.

I am using prototypejs...

Comment: What `datepicker` are you using? There *should* be a method to return a locale-independent date.

Comment: we have apache tapestry5 framework at presentation layer, so we are using default tapestry5 datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Date.parse()` in your code:

```
var startDate = Date.parse($('startDate'+counter).value);
```

Comment: what returns `$('startDate'+counter).value` ?

Comment: 30/03/2012 for es and 03/30/2012 for en. Giving a 'NaN' error for 30/03/2012 and working fine for 03/30/2012 with Date.parse(...)

Comment: Do you know in your script which language is used? If you know, just change date from specific format to common format: http://jsfiddle.net/UVnFc/